# Remove older elements from a list

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, for-loop, iteration

I'm trying to remove similar elements from a list that contains a sub_list with the elements' name, date, and additional data:

`basket = [['cheese', '2015/04/16', 'junk'],['apple', '2015/04/15', 'other junk'],['apple', '2015/03/15', 'dessert'],['cheese', '2017/04/16', 'pie'],['banana', '2015/04/16', ''],['cheese', '2017/04/10', '']]`

If an element name (fruit) appears twice in the list, the program should compare the date and remove the older element. I'm using **datetime** to compare the the second element and this part is working. But when I iterate through the list, it keeps skipping `'banana'`. And this should be the last item to be added.

I've tried this method:

```
def date_convert(date):
    """Takes a date string in the form YYYY/MM/DD and converts it to a
       date object for comparisons."""

    # Split date string by ".", " ", "/", or "-" to handle a wider range
    # of possible inputs.
    date = re.split('[. /\-]', date)

    # Strip month of "0" because datetime does not accept that as valid
    # input.
    if(date[1][0] == '0'):
        date[1] = date[1].strip('0')

    return datetime.date(int(date[0]), int(date[1]), int(date[2]))        




basket = [['cheese', '2015/04/16'],['apple', '2015/04/15'],['apple', '2015/03/15'],['cheese', '2017/04/16'],['banana', '2015/04/16'],['cheese', '2017/04/10']]

new_basket = []

for food in basket:
    basket.remove(food)
    for food2 in basket:
        if food[0].upper() == food2[0].upper():
            basket.remove(food2)

            if date_convert(food[1]) > date_convert(food2[1]):
                pass
            else:
                food = food2
    else: new_basket.append(food)

print str(new_basket)
```

and receive this printout: `[['cheese', '2017/04/16', 'pie'], ['apple', '2015/04/15', 'other junk']]`

According to the debugger, it never reaches banana in the for loop.

Comment: Is the order in the output list important? Thanks.

Comment: For the method? Possibly. But not at all for the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option. Grouping by the first items of the inner sublists using [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict). Using `max()` to find the maximum date with a custom `key` function that would help to compare the date strings as actual dates:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from datetime import datetime

basket = [['cheese', '2015/04/16', 'junk'],['apple', '2015/04/15', 'other junk'],['apple', '2015/03/15', 'dessert'],['cheese', '2017/04/16', 'pie'],['banana', '2015/04/16', ''],['cheese', '2017/04/10', '']]

d = defaultdict(list)
for item in basket:
    d[item[0]].append(item[1:])

print([[key, max(values, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[0], "%Y/%m/%d"))] for key, values in d.items()])
```

Prints:

```
[['apple', ['2015/04/15', 'other junk']], ['banana', ['2015/04/16', '']], ['cheese', ['2017/04/16', 'pie']]]
```

Note that you would lose the order in this case.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I needed, but there's one small issue. Each sublist has additional entries after the date(updated the question). I can't seem to include these with the sort.

Comment: Thanks for the help.